# Me devuelve un string vacio / Vue

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un input en vue:

```
<w-input
                type="text"
                :value="googleTagManagerCode"
                :maxlength="12"
                placeholder="GTM-XXXXXX"
                @change="updateInput"
              />
```

y en mi data:

```
data () {
    return {
        googleTagManagerCode: ''
      }
```

y la siguiente función en methods:

```
async Confirm () {
      helperModal.showWindowContentLoading()
      let response = await ApiService.post('/config/updateExtraConfiguration', {
        google_tag_manager_code: this.googleTagManagerCode
      });

      if (response.success) {
        this.messageManager.showSuccessMessage(this.translateText('Se han guardado correctamente los cambios.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
        this.closeModal()
      } else {
        this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText('No se han podido guardar los cambios. Intenta nuevamente.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      }
    },
```

Cuestion que cuando ingreso en el input de la pagina, el codigo de tag manager (ej: GTM-123456) y hago click en guardar, me pone que los cambios se realizaron correctamente pero checkeando en network de la consola, veo que lo envia vacio (ej: google_tag_manager_code: "")

Como verifico que se este enviando cuando guarda?
Porque envia vacio?

Comment: De que tipo de objeto es w-input? porque esta en value y no en bind?

Comment: Y tambien la funcion que llama es updateInput que supongo llama a confirm no?

Comment: que tiene la funcion updateInput. Deberias hacer uso de v-model es mas simple ademas antes de hacer el envio de la información puedes usar el devtools del chrome , el opera o el mozilla con la extención de Vue para que veas que tiene realmente ese componente en su value, incluso cuando estas cambiandole el valor en runtime.

Comment: @gbianchi w-input es como b-input de vue. con respecto a bind, como seria de esa manera? no estoy usando updateInput, será por eso que no vincula el dato ingresado al guardar?

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas como seria con v-model?

Comment: quita el @change i lo que hace esto es actualizar la propiedad googleTagManagerCode, quita el :value y pon v-model="googleTagManagerCode"

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
             <w-input
                type="text"
                :value="googleTagManagerCode"
                :maxlength="12"
                placeholder="GTM-XXXXXX"
                @change="UpdateTagManagerCode"
              />
```

en data: `googleTagManagerCode: null`

y en methods:

```
UpdateTagManagerCode (value) {
      this.googleTagManagerCode = value
```